# unable to add active resource gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

when i am executing **bundle install** command i am getting this error

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    activeresource (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 2.0.1) ruby

```
rails (= 4.0.0.rc1) ruby depends on
  activesupport (4.0.0.rc1)
```

**this is my gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activeresource', :require => 'active_resource'
```

**Ruby => ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]**

**Rails => Rails 4.0.0.rc1**

Please help!

Comment: delete Gemfile.lock and then try bundle install

Answer (score 0):

try the command :bundle update
 it will also update 'activesupport' to the latest version